# ETH transactions to presale contract keep failing

Tags: erc-20, kovan, presale, failed-transaction

I'm trying to send some ETH to a presale smart contract on Kovan. Allowance has been set with presale address as a spender - with the exact same amount as the tokens allocated in the presale contract.
But then I got:

**Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]**
at tx hash:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x8d0451f2a9ba2440bf5f2a27d171850437772ccb12afeb8846507c0497e65cc0

From what I've read and learned, there's something wrong during the token transfer. But I can't find which one it is.

Would like to know if there's a way to fix this issue or at least knowing which one caused this, in case I'm facing the same issue in the future. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the service https://tenderly.co/ to debug your transactions on live nets.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa how about testnet?

Comment: Supported Networks: Mainnet, Kovan, Rinkeby, Ropsten, Görli, xDai, POA Network, Matic Mainnet, Matic Testnet v3, Matic Mumbai, Binance Smart Chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Bad instruction` and the gas consumption equal to gas limit `1,000,000` indicates the problem was caused by an assert or low level error like array out of bound access.

Looking at the receive function none of the transfers should cause Bad Instruction. Failed transfers revert but do not consume all available gas.

After discarding mapping access, and the `require`s conditions the only suspicious code is getTokensPerEth function

```
function getTokensPerEth(uint256 amount) internal view returns(uint256) {
    return amount.mul(tokenRatePerEth).div(
        10**(uint256(9).sub(tokenDecimals).add(rateDecimals))
        );
}
```

The failure is at `uint256(9).sub(tokenDecimals)`. Since `tokenDecimals` is 18 SafeMath's `sub` will fail at `assert(b <= a)` (b = 18, a = 9).

Comment: Such a great answer! Thanks a lot Ismael!